# Delete last div on a web page with PHP preg_replace

Tags: php

I have a web page that is a series of 28-31 daily report all enclosed in a `div`:

```
<div class="day_report">...</div>
```

I am trying to delete the last report from the page using

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://somesite.html/temp.html');
$pattern='/(?s)<div class="day_report">.*?</div>/';
preg_replace($pattern, $homepage, $results);
echo $results[0];
?>
```

I don't know if I've got the pattern wrong or my usage of `preg_replace` is incorrect, but it's not working as the `div` is not being deleted. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

One error is: the last bit of your RegEx pattern won't work as you haven't escaped out the `/` in `... </div>`. If you don't escape out the `/` the system will think it's the end of the RegEx and get very confused!

It should look like: `... <\/div>`

There may well be other mistakes though.
What I would do as a strategy is to start off trying to match and replace just a *small* part of the pattern. Start with a pattern like `/<div /` and work up from there...

Comment: Thanks. Escaping the / is what I was missing BUT it is now deleting the first instance of the div, I want to delete the last instance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `preg_replace($pattern, $homepage, $results);`, you would have something like `$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $homepage);`. [RTFD](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

As @Annabel said, you also have an error in your regex. I'd suggest using something like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to verify your code.

Comment: Thank you, regex101 is very a very useful resource.